# Why is this variable considered an lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

Considering this code

```
class T {
public:
    T(T& x) = delete;
    T(T&& x) {}
};

void foo(T&& b) {
    T y(b);
}
```

I was expecting that b; which is an rvalue by declaration; and seemingly usage, should be passed into the move constructor of T in foo().

Instead; I get a compilation error reporting that T& has been deleted.

Replacing it with

```
void foo(T&& c) {
    T y(std::move(c));
}
```

Results in the expected success; but obviously one doesn't want to litter their code with std::move everywhere.
As tempting as it is to blame visual studio - in this case I suspect it's my understanding that's wrong.  Can someone please explain why move constructor isn't used?

Comment: Remember, anything with a name is an lvalue, no matter what the source of it is.

Comment: table flipping goodness

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it, since named thing can be on the left hand side of an assignment operator.  I for one had to hammer this rule into my head as well as the rvalueness of the reference kept trying to distract me.

Comment: "_Names of `rvalue reference` variables are `lvalues` and have to be converted to `xvalues` to be bound to the function overloads that accept `rvalue reference` parameters, which is why move constructors and move assignment operators typically use `std::move`_" [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Comment: @NathanOliver template parameters and enumeration constants are exceptions to that rule